# System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified path format is not supported.'

Tags: c#, xml, file

I have a field in a table that needs to be filled with the path and the end of the XML file to create a new file in the directory called `DONE`. This is made so it can tidy the directory a bit since the ones that are done don't need to be in the same directory so they are copied from one place into another.

Why is there this error?

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified path format is not supported.'

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Ficheiro processado: " + filename);
string rootFolderPath = @"C:\XMLFiles";
string destinationPath = @"C:\XMLFiles\DONE";
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath);
foreach (string file1 in fileList)
{
    string fileToMove = rootFolderPath + file1;
    string moveTo = destinationPath + file1;
    File.Move(fileToMove, moveTo);
    da.SP_Insert(filename, file.Name, batch.BatchClassName, batch.Name, batch.Description, 0, "", 1, moveTo );
}
```

Comment: Unless `file1` starts a backslash, the file path will be either invalid or simply wrong.

Comment: you should verify that your fileToMove and moveTo have a value like 
`"C:\XMLFiles\file1.xml"`

Comment: what do you mean? @JesúsNarváez

Comment: @TiagoSilva I mean that while debugging, you could put a breakpoint and see the value of the variables `fileToMove` and `moveTo` to check if the route was properly constructed :). Its related to the answers that are considering that `Directory.GetFiles()` will return the whole path (ex `c:\foo\mzfile.xml`) instead of just `myfile.xml`. You should check that `file1` contains only the filename.

Comment: File1 is returning the whole path how can i fix that? @JesúsNarváez

Comment: @TiagoSilva You can fix it using the `FileInfo` class like I suggested in my answer

Comment: fixed it, by the way why cant i post anymore questions?

Comment: @TiagoSilva maybe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit

Comment: @JayV nah i think its cause of my previous question did bad but i was at 0 reputation im at 17 now doesne´t that help in 3 days 17 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem was fixed this way.

```
                    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
                    {

                        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            string CaminhoInicial = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(CaminhoInicial);
                            File.Copy(CaminhoInicial, CaminhoFinal + g.ToString() + fi.Extension, true);
                            da.SP_Inserir_Imagem(id, g.ToString() + fi.Extension);
                        }

                    }

                    try
                    {


                        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                        {
                            string NomeImagem = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(CaminhoFinal + NomeImagem.Replace(" ", ""));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "    ||||    " + ex.StackTrace, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    }
```

Also read this Microfost Docs post for more context.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 3):

The function `Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath);` returns the full path to the file, that is filename and directory. If, like you are trying, want the filename only, you will need to extract it.

The `FileInfo` class is very good at extracting the Filename only of a full path.

```
foreach (string file1 in fileList)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file1);
    string moveTo = Path.Combine( destinationPath, fi.Name);
    File.Move(file1, moveTo);
}
```

Comment: no no i need the full path for finding file porpuses since i use that variable to store in the db aswell

Comment: The full path of the original is in the variable `file1`, the full path of the new location is in `moveTo`

Comment: @TiagoSilva then what is it you are objecting to? What I am suggesting moves the file to the `destinationPath` which was causing the `NotSupportedException`

Comment: Can you tell us what the value of the `file1` and `moveTo` variables are please? You can get the value from the `Locals` window

Comment: move to is the diresctory the file is going and file is the name of the file trough the list of files

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `string fileToMove = rootFolderPath + file1`, try using `System.IO.Path.Combine` instead:

```
var fileToMove  = Path.Combine(rootFolderPath, file1);
var moveTo = Path.Combine(destinationPath , file1);
```

Comment: I did still gives the same error and its highligthing this line File.Move(fileToMove, moveTo);

Comment: Both `file1` and `rootFolderPath` will have the full path (with the `C:\`). Wonder if Path.Combine will be smart enough

Comment: @TiagoSilva did you fix *both* paths? The code you use right now generates invalid paths

Comment: i did the pathCombine for both and still gives that error , @Cleptus man why you took out my bad programmer bit its what i am haha

Comment: Ye its a directory called XMLFiles that is gonna hve a lot of xml files that are processed and arent so ye the user as access cause its employees using only

Comment: Unexperienced is not the same as bad. Your coding style is fine, you only need practice and API knowledge

Comment: @Cleptus thank you tho but like i still get the error i wonder if i made a mistake in the path making

Comment: @TiagoSilva I think this answer is wrong, check the other answers (they use only the file name, not the full path of `file1`)

Comment: ye i was seeing it it wont help in this case thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

[`GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) returns **full paths**; not just filenames:

> Returns the names of files (**including their paths**) in the specified directory

So for the source files you don't need to combine anything, and for the target path you need to split off the filename first before combining:

```
foreach (string file1 in fileList)
{
    string moveTo = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(file1));
    File.Move(file1, moveTo);
    // ...
}
```